# Como compilar Less ou Sass automaticamente?

Tags: sass, less

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida em relação ao Less/Sass. Hoje em dia trabalho somente com o Sublime Text para desenvolver os meu sites, e utilizo o Sass ou o Less para os estilos e uso o Koala para compilá-los.

Porém gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta que me permita compilar esses meus arquivos de estilo  automaticamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode instalar o [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) na sua máquina. Ele serve para rodar diversas aplicações que você pode baixar no [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/), dentre elas o [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/).

O Gulp automatiza diversas operações para você. Aliado ao [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass), por exemplo, você poderá compilar seus arquivos SASS automaticamente a cada vez que forem salvos - o plugin fica observando o diretório onde eles estão e reage a modificações.

Já para LESS, você pode usar o [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less). O princípio é o mesmo.

As instruções de uso do gulp e de seus plugins está na página de cada um. São apenas algumas poucas linhas de script para cada um deles.

Só um aviso: Node.js já é viciante por si só, mas sua combinação com NPM leva a um caminho sem volta :)